# How I can draw Diagonal line between canvas shape

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want draw a Diagonal line between circles. How I can do this? this is part of my code:

```
<div id="ways" style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;height:100%;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</div>
```

and complete [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/testtest/o256ppwx/)

I want create lines for center circle like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can draw it the same as other lines:

```
    if (i != rows - 1 && j != cols - 1) {
        context.moveTo(
            x + radius / sqrt2,
            y + radius / sqrt2
        );
        context.lineTo(
            (j + 1) * offset + center - radius / sqrt2,
            (i + 1) * offset + center - radius / sqrt2
        );
        context.moveTo(
            x + radius / sqrt2,
            (i + 1) * offset + center - radius / sqrt2
        );
        context.lineTo(
            (j + 1) * offset + center - radius / sqrt2,
            y + radius / sqrt2
        );
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o256ppwx/2/

Comment: It's true, but I want diagonal lines like 'X' between circle!

Comment: Excuse me! if row numbers be 3, How I draw a diagonal line between first top corner and bottom right corner and top-right corner and bottom-left corner? plz help! thanks!

Comment: I want just red lines and must like in question image (question edited)!